# Converting to Secret Language

Tags: popularity-contest

Write some code in any language that inputs a string such as "Today is a great day" (Note that there is no punctuation) and converts it to the "Secret Language". Here are the rules for the "Secret Language".

- a=c, b=d, c=e and so on (y=a and z=b)
- separate each word by a space
- make sure there is proper capitalization

Example:

```
Input: "Today is a great day"

Output: "Vqfca ku c itgcv fca"
```

It is a popularity-contest. Other users should give points by looking for most "to the point" yet "unique" code.

CHALLENGE:
I was looking up uncommon programming languages and I found a language called [Piet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language#Piet) ([esolang](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet)). I challenge anyone to write it in this language.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `x=z, y=a, z=b`?

Comment: you are right "duh" :)

Comment: I was confused until I realized `a=c` is `a -> c`.

Comment: In other words, [ROT2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) it

Comment: Both rot13 and rot2 are both [Caesar ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with different keys (13 and 2).

Comment: We are trying to make the code elegantly functional, right? I hope this does not descend into an obfuscation contest.

Comment: I went for the feature rich Python version :-)

Answer (score 20):

## Smalltalk (Smalltalk/X), <strike>29</strike> 27 chars

I am lucky - it is already in the String class:

```
'Today is a great day' rot:2
    -> 'Vqfca ku c itgcv fca'
```

adding I/O, this makes it:

```
(Stdin nextLine rot:2)print
```

in the spirit of doorknob's obfuscated example below, how about:

```
Parser evaluate:('(Uvfkp pgzvNkpg tqv:2)rtkpvPN' rot:-2)
```

Comment: I never thought I'd see a Smalltalk solution!

Answer (score 15):

### Postscript

The HQ requires, that from now on all agents shall receive communication in printed form only (as electronic channels proved too unreliable) using special top secret font. It is your responsibility to include this top secret procedure into prologue of our printing software:

```
/define_Secret_font {
    /Secret_font
    /Coronet findfont dup 
    /Encoding get 
    aload pop 256 array astore 
    /secret_proc {
        2 copy
        26 getinterval aload pop 
        26 -2 roll 26 array astore
        putinterval
    } def
    dup 65 secret_proc
    dup 97 secret_proc
    exch dup length dict dup
    3 -1 roll {put dup} forall
    exch /Encoding 4 -1 roll put 
    definefont pop
} def
```

And only that font is allowed, e.g.:

```
define_Secret_font
/Secret_font 36 selectfont
0 841 translate
20 -60 moveto
(Today is a great day) show
20 -120 moveto
(Programming Puzzles & Code Golf) show
showpage
```

And that's what it prints:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

## Ruby, obfuscated edition (with commentary included!)

I suggest reading the entire thing; I find it quite amusing ;)

```
$s='';class Module;def const_missing c

# MAGIC:
$s+="#{c}".split("#{$;}").map{|x|x.ord-8**2}.reduce(:"#{43.chr}").chr;end;end

              # My commentary ;)

ZZZY          # ?
YAYYY         # Oookay; you seem excited
Yaz           # Typo?
Yay           # Better
JEEEEEEF      # You misspelled Jeff's name
LAZZZY        # Yes, you are very lazy
Yax           # Another typo...
LLAMA         # Definitely not completely random at all...
EEEEEEEEEEEEE # Ouch my ears
IIIII         # Ouch stop
ASDFASDFASDF  # I SAID STOP BANGING ON THE KEYBOARD
YUMMY         # ... you eat keyboards?
IIIII         # Stop!
YUMMYY        # Why are you eating your keyboard
LLAMA         # That doesn't make sense :(
VV            # :(
LLAMA         # Could you stop saying that?!
CODEGOLF      # Yay, one of my favorite SE sites! :D
VW            # I don't drive
ASDFASDFASDF  # Why do you keep banging on your keyboard?!?!
EEEEEEEEEEEEE # No
VVV           # Stop
HELLOo        # ...it's a little late for a greeting, isn't it?
DOGS          # ...
OOOOOo        # No, you're not a ghost.
HELLOOOO      # Just a *bit* late.
NNNNNNN       # Huh?
LLAMA         # I said to stop.

print eval$s
```

Hints on how it works (spoilers, hover to show):

> This code builds a string and then evaluates it.

> It uses `const_missing` in order to build the string character by character.

> The string it ends up building is `gets.tr'A-Za-z','C-ZABc-zab'`.

Comment: The commentary reads like some of the chats in this question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20914/who-is-this-chatbot/20926#20926

Answer (score 11):

## bash

Classic.

```
tr A-Za-z C-ZABc-zab
```

Example:

```
$ tr A-Za-z C-ZABc-zab <<< "Today is a great day"
Vqfca ku c itgcv fca
```

Comment: I think you don't need the quotes.

Comment: @marinus You're right, I'll change it.

Answer (score 6):

DFSORT (IBM Mainframe sorting program)

```
 OPTION COPY
 INREC BUILD=(1,80,TRAN=ALTSEQ)
```

No SORT control statement can start in column one.

For the above to work on its own, you'd have to change the default installation alternate translation table, to offset all values for upper- and lower-case letters, wrapping around the final two letters.

Without changing the default table, it would require an ALTSEQ statement listing all the required pairs of hex values (from-hex-code immediately followed by to-hex-code, each pair of hex values separated by a comma):

```
 OPTION COPY
 INREC BUILD=(1,80,TRAN=ALTSEQ)
 ALTSEQ CODE=(xxyy,...)
```

So to get upper-case EBCDIC A to C and B to D:

ALTSEQ CODE=(C1C3,C2C4)

For the whole thing, that would be a lot of error-prone typing, of course, so you'd use another SORT step to generate the control cards for this step, and let SORT read them from the dataset created by that new step.

Of course, for any language which supports a "translation table", it is as easy as changing the translation table. Nice COBOL program, with a specific Codepage, and it could be done in one line of COBOL procedure code (plus the obligatory lines of COBOL that go with everything... not so many in this particular case).

Oh, the 1,80 is the "card image" which will contain the text. Probably all in upper-case on the first run...

Comment: +1. Using DFSORT for ROT2 is really unique.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 75 bytes

```
main(c){while((c=getchar())>0)putchar(isalpha(c)?(c&224)+((c&31)+2)%26:c);}
```

Example:

```
$echo "Today is a great day" |./a.out
Vqfca ku c itgcv fca
```

Comment: assuming EOF is -1 you may use the bitwise not `~(c=getchar())` to save 1 char

Comment: and since the question says there are no punctuations the only non-alphabetical character is space, so you may test for it with `c-32` instead, which saves you 6 chars

Comment: This is a popularity contest and not code-golf

Comment: Code golf is antithetical to popularity now?

Comment: @user689 you're right, sorry I didn't read the question carefully. Since this code is written in a single line with ternary operator and no `int`, and even a char count is provided, I somehow assumed that it was code golf. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, it's actually understandable.

I know that anything with whitespace and parentheses has a hard time on CG, but here's a shot.

```java
    class SecretLanguage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String S : args) {
        for (char s : S.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print((char) (s + ((s < 'y') ? 2 : -24)));
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    }
}
```

There are separate contests for obfuscating code, but I can make mine ridiculous too.

```java
class S{public static void main(String[]args){for(String str:args){for(char i:(str).toCharArray())System.out.print((char)(i+((i<'y')?2:-24)));System.out.print(" ");}}
```

Answer (score 3):

### PHP

Not the shortest one though!

Live example: https://eval.in/102173

```
<?php
$str = 'Today is a great day';
$out = implode('', array_map(function ($val) {
  if ($val == ' ') return ' ';
  $c = ord($val)+2;

  if (ctype_lower($val)) {
    if ($c > ord('z')) {
      return chr(ord('`') + ($c - ord('z')));
    }
    return chr($c);
  }
  else {
    if ($c > ord('Z')) {
      return chr(ord('A') + ($c - ord('Z')));
    }
    return chr($c);
  }  
}, str_split($str)));

var_dump($out);
```

Note:

```
ord('`') = ord('a') - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

TI-Basic (the language that runs on TI-83 graphing calculators)

```
:ClrHome  
:" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" //all symbols that can be interpreted  
:Ans+Ans+Ans->Str1  
:Menu("crippter","encript",1,"decript",2  
:Lbl 2  
:1->C  
:Lbl 1  
:if not(C)  
:Imput ">",Str2  
:if C  
:Imput "<",Str2  
:length(Str2)->D  
:lenght(Str1)/3->E  
:if not(C)  
:Then  
:randInt(1,E)->B  
:sub(Str1,B,1)->Str3  
:Else  
:inString(Str1,sub(Str2,1,1),1)->B  
":"->Str3  
:For(X,1+C,D  
:inString(Str1,sub(Str2,X,1)->A  
:if not(C  
:A+E-B-X->A  
:if C  
:A+B+X-1->A  
:Str3+sub(Str1,A,1)->Str3  
:End  
:if C  
:sub(Str3,2,D-1)->Str3  
:Pause Str3  
:Goto A
```

This is some nice encryption software (for a TI-83). By ti-83 I mean any calculator in the ti-83 or ti-84 family. "->" means "STORE" accessed by "STO>"

Comment: This doesn't work, at least on the TI-84 family -- `//` doesn't define comments (in fact, there is no way to get comments), every `If` requires a `Then`, and it's impossible to have a line that doesn't start with a colon (as you have with `":"->Str3`).

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby <del>40</del> 32**

```
p gets.tr("A-XY-Za-xy-z","C-ZA-Bc-za-b")
```

update (as seen from danieros bash solution):

```
p gets.tr("A-Za-z","C-ZABc-zab")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I'll ROT2 it!

### Javascript

```
function r(a,b){return++b?String.fromCharCode((a<"["?91:123)>(a=a.charCodeAt()+2)?a:a-26):a.replace(/[A-z]/g,r)}

console.log(r('Qccipcr'));
```

Comment: I thought about something like that at first, but I never thought of `[A-z]`!

Answer (score 2):

## Python

```
a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
b = list('yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx')

c = {}

#generate conversion dictionary

for i in range(len(a)):
    c[a[i]] = b[i]

instring = "the weather is very nice today"

outstring = ""

for i in list(instring):
    try:
        outstring += c[i]
    except:
        outstring += i

print outstring
```

Output:

rfc ucyrfcp gq tcpw lgac rmbyw

Comment: (1) It's `+3`, right? (2) You could inline a lot of stuff to make it more complicated. (that seems to be a trend here)

Comment: `b = a[2:] + a[:2]` would be less typo-prone, and there seems to be no need to convert the string `a` to a `list`

Comment: oh, and `c = dict(zip(a,b))`. And the `except` shouldn't be so generic, use an `except KeyError`

Comment: `str` concatenation is super slow. Create a `list` and join them together would be much better.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript

```
var str = '';
var textInput = 'myString';
for (var i = 0; i < textInput.length; i++) {
    str += textInput.charAt(i).replace(/([a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]*$/, function (a) {
        var c = a.charCodeAt(0);
        switch (c) {
            case 89:
                return 'A'; //Letter Y!
            case 90:
                return 'B'; //Letter Z!
            case 121:
                return 'a'; //Letter y!
            case 122: //Letter z!
                return 'b';
            default:
                return String.fromCharCode(c + 2); //If not y, Y, z, or Z, then just two more from the usual char code
        }
    })
}
console.log(str);
```

What with all the comments, my hamster can understand this.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript

```
// setup alphabet and secret rotated alphabet
//
var alpha=' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
var rotor=' cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab'
alpha+=alpha.toUpperCase()
rotor+=rotor.toUpperCase()

function encrypt(str) {
 return crypt(str, alpha, rotor)
}

function decrypt(str) {
 return crypt(str, rotor, alpha)
}

// swap position of char from one dictionary to the other
function crypt(msg, d1, d2) {
 var out=''
 var len=str.length
 for(var i=0; i < len; i++) {
  var c = msg.charAt(i)
  var j = d1.indexOf(c)
  out += d2.charAt(j)
 }
 return out
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.x

An attempt at a feature rich Python solution.

Features:

- the use of a dict
- handling the list in a circular way, so that `shift=2` can be varied
- you can also use it to decipher when you know `shift` (just use minus), it'll also allows you to test your output.
- ability to add "shifting scopes" -- scopes in which you cycle
- option to either be `strict` for undefined characters, or just return the undefined input character.
- a secret language leaves no trace ;)

Here goes:

```
# Shifting scopes
lower_case = map(chr, range(97, 123))
upper_case = map(chr, range(65, 91))
space = [" "] # space will always be transformed to space

def secret(instring, shift, scopes, strict=False):
    def buildTranslationDict(scores):
        translation_dict = {}
        for scope in scopes: 
            for index in range(len(scope)): 
                translation_dict[scope[index]] = scope[(index+shift) % len(scope)]
        return translation_dict 
    translation_dict = buildTranslationDict(scopes)
    # Use the translation dictionary to transform input
    output = ""        
    for char in instring:
        if strict:
           output += translation_dict[char]   # will crash if unexpected char
        else:
            try:    
               output += translation_dict[char]
            except: 
               output += char
    return output
```

Proof:

```
secret(instring="Today is a great day", shift=2, scopes=[lower_case, upper_case, space])
'Vqfca ku c itgcv fca'
```

Can you decipher `'Wrpruurz lv qrw edg hlwkhu!'` :) ?

Comment: Just curious, do you consider adding this extra "strict" feature *"not to the point"*?

Comment: It would save 6 lines of code...

Comment: Are you talking to yourself or am I missing something? Like deleted comments?

Comment: Yup deleted, please do not delete your comment as well...

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell

Here's a lens based implementation. I'm using `Iso` to represent the isomorphism between regular text and text converted into the secret language. Unless you provide the `--from` option, the input is converted into the secret language. If the `--from` option is provided, the opposite conversion is performed.

```hs
module Main where
import Control.Lens
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Char          (ord, chr, isUpper, isSpace)
import Data.Word          (Word8)

ord8 :: Char -> Word8
ord8 = fromIntegral . ord

chr8 :: Word8 -> Char
chr8 = chr . fromIntegral

ordIso :: Iso' Char Word8
ordIso = iso ord8 chr8

firstLetterOrd :: Word8 -> Word8
firstLetterOrd n
  | n ^. from ordIso . to isUpper = ord8 'A'
  | otherwise                     = ord8 'a'

secretChar :: Iso' Char Char
secretChar =
  iso toSecret
      fromSecret
  where
    toSecret, fromSecret :: Char -> Char
    toSecret   = secretConversion   2
    fromSecret = secretConversion (-2)

secretConversion :: Int -> Char -> Char
secretConversion n c
  | isSpace c = c
  | otherwise = c & over ordIso (secretShift n)

secretShift :: Int -> Word8 -> Word8
secretShift shiftAmount =
  preserveLetters $ (`mod` 26) . (+ shiftAmount)

preserveLetters :: (Int -> Int) -> Word8 -> Word8
preserveLetters fn n =
  firstLetter + overWord8 fn (n - firstLetter)
  where
    firstLetter = firstLetterOrd n

overWord8 :: (Int -> Int) -> Word8 -> Word8
overWord8 fn = fromIntegral . fn . fromIntegral

help :: IO ()
help =
  putStr
  $ unlines
      ["SecretLang [--from]"
      ,"If the --from option is provided, the program"
      ,"converts from the secret language. Otherwise,"
      ,"it converts to the secret language."
      ]

convertContents :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
convertContents fn = do
  input <- getContents
  putStrLn . ("Output: " ++) $ fn input

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs

  case args of
    ("--from":_) ->
      convertContents (^. mapping (from secretChar))

    ("--help":_) -> help
    ("-h"    :_) -> help

    _            ->
      convertContents (^. mapping secretChar)
```

Examples:

```
$ ./SecretLang
Today is a great day
Output: Vqfca ku c itgcv fca

$ ./SecretLang --from
Vqfca ku c itgcv fca
Output: Today is a great day
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Powershell

```
$chars = [int]('a')[0]..[int]('z')[0] | %{ [char]$_, [char]::ToUpper([char]$_) }

$y = $args[0].ToCharArray() | %{
    $idx = $chars.indexOf($_);
    if ($idx -ge 0) {
        $chars[($idx + 4) % 52]
    } else  {
        $_
    } 
}

-join [char[]]$y
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Temp> .\z.ps1 "Today is a great day"
Vqfca ku c itgcv fca
PS C:\Temp>
```

Answer (score 1):

## C

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    { char p[256];
    int i;
    fgets ( p, 256, stdin );
    for(i=0; i<256 ; i++)
    {
   if ( p[i] == '\n' )
    {
    p[i] = '\0';
    break;
    }
    else
    {

    if((p[i] >= 'a' && p[i] <= 'x') || (p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'X') )
    {
        p[i] +=2;
    }

    else
    {
    switch(p[i])
     {
        case 'y':    p[i] = 'a';
                     break;

       case 'Y':    p[i] = 'A';
                     break;

       case 'z':    p[i] = 'b';
                     break;
       case 'Z':    p[i] = 'B';
                     break;
       case ' ':    p[i] = ' ';
                     break;


     }
    }
}}

printf("%s", p);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: you can save a lot of code by using modulu arithmetic on the chars...

Comment: @blabla999 this is a popularity contest and not code-golf

Comment: sorry - not meant to offend. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

## EcmaScript 6:

```
alert(prompt(_='').split(_).map(x=>String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt()+(x>' '?x>'x'|x>'X'&x<'['?-24:2:0))).join(_))
```

Comment: EcmaScript, my devolved ol' enemy

Answer (score 1):

**JAVA**

`32` is `space` so we print it out as is
`88` is `X` so anything less than `89` moves up 2 characters
`90` is `Z` so anything less than `91` moves down 24 characters (with anything less than `89` already handled so only `89` and `90` effectively)
Repeat same process for lowercase letters, ranging from `97` as `a` to `122` as `z`.

```
void secret(String s) {
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print((char)(c == 32 ? c : c < 89 ? c + 2 : c < 91 ? c - 24 : c < 121 ? c + 2 : c - 24));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

This solution is rather boring:

```
echo strtr('Today is a great day','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab');
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3

I think i didn't quite understand the question, but anyway:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
rot = alphabet[2:] + alphabet[:2]
rot = rot + rot.upper()
alphabet = alphabet + alphabet.upper()

def encode_letter(letter):
    return rot[alphabet.index(letter)]

def encode_word(word):
    return "".join(encode_letter(letter) for letter in word)

def encode_string(string):
    return " ".join(encode_word(word) for word in string.split())

print("Output: " + encode_string(input("Input: ")))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (V8)

```js
t=>t.replace(/./g,d=>/[a-z]/i.test(d)?((parseInt(d,36)-8)%26+10).toString(36)[/[A-Z]/.test(d)?"toUpperCase":"valueOf"]():d)
```

This is code golf, short *is* popular.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

```python
# To understand recursion, go to the bottom of the program

from string import ascii_letters

translate_table = {
    c: chr(ord(c) + 2) for c in ascii_letters
}


def translate_helper(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        if string not in {"y", "z"}:
            return translate_table[string]
        else:
            return "a" if string == "y" else "b"
    else:
        return translate_helper(string[:-1]) + translate_helper(string[-1])


def translate(string):
    return " ".join(map(translate_helper, string.split(" ")))


print(translate("Today is a great day"))

# To understand recursion, go to the top of the program
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 255 bytes

```
const sl = text =>
  text
    .split(" ")
    .map(word =>
      word
        .split("")
        .map(c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + (c < "y" ? 2 : -24)))
        .join("")
    )
    .join(" ");

console.log(sl("Today is a great day"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! There's a lot of byte saves possible here, like removing whitespace and shortening variable names (like changing `word` to `w`). I'd recommend checking out our [Tips for Golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) for more!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal)

```
@rotate:letter|
 kL ←letter c [
   ←letter \Y = [
     \A | ←letter \y = [
       \a | ←letter \Z = [
         \B | ←letter \z = [
           \b | ←letter C 2 + C 
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ] | ←letter
 ]
;

`Today is a great day`f °rotate; M ¤j
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%40rotate%3Aletter%7C%0A%20kL%20%E2%86%90letter%20c%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%E2%86%90letter%20%5CY%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5CA%20%7C%20%E2%86%90letter%20%5Cy%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ca%20%7C%20%E2%86%90letter%20%5CZ%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5CB%20%7C%20%E2%86%90letter%20%5Cz%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cb%20%7C%20%E2%86%90letter%20C%202%20%2B%20C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%5D%20%7C%20%E2%86%90letter%0A%20%5D%0A%3B%0A%0A%60Today%20is%20a%20great%20day%60f%20%C2%B0rotate%3B%20M%20%C2%A4j&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Finally, a chance to use the more obscure features of Vyxal! Behold the beauty of named functions, variables, if-else chains and function references. I also got to make good use of the codemirror functionality built into the online interpreter for once.

Also, I know caird said not to, but I answered anyway, because I never get the chance to properly show off the cooler stuff of my esolang.

Answer (score 0):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/)

Since this is a popularity contest I've written this with the intention
of it being as easy to follow as EBF can be. It's heavily commented and
I've intentionally used macros to make the program flow more literal.

Probably the most difficult thing here is the main switch since EBF doesn't have any special means of doing it so it's in reality no simpler than how one would do it in BrainFuck except for the variables and balancing parentheses.

```
;;;; rot2.ebf : Perform rot2 on ascii text
;;;; Usage: bf ebf.bf < rot2.ebf > rot2.bf
;;;;        echo "Today is a great day" | bf rot2.bf
;;;;        # => Vqfca ku c itgcv fca
;;;;
;;;; BF interpreter/Compiler requirement: 
;;;; Wrapping cells at any size (allmost all of them do)
;;;;


;;; Memory map  
:tmp    ; a temporary cell used for the read routine
:input  ; a copy of the input for output purposes
:switch ; a copy of the input for the switch statements
:flag   ; flag to indicate the predicate has been processed or not

;;; Macros
;; Ultracompatible read
;; supports EOF 0, -1 and no change
{read_tmp 
  $input+ 
  $tmp(-),
  [+[-$input-]] ; blanks for all EOFs
  $switch [
    @input &clear
    $switch
  ]
}

;; for the switch we need
;; to do destructive testing
;; and we need to preserve the
;; original as well. 
{copy_input 
  $tmp(-$input+$switch+)
}

;; clears the cell
{clear (-)}

;; prints current cell
{print .}

;;; Main proram
;;; flow starts here
&read_tmp
while $tmp not eof
(
  &copy_input
  $flag+
  $switch 10-(22-(
    ;; not linefeed/space
    $switch 57-(-(31-(-(
       ;; default: not wrapping
       &clear
       $flag-
       $input 2+))))
    $flag (-
       ;; wrapping
       $input 24-)))
  $flag &clear
  $input &print &clear
  &read_tmp
)
;;; End
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
var STR = "Today is a great day";
//so i can replace chars at a index in the string
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(i, char) {
    var a = this.split("");
    a[i] = char;
    return a.join("");
}

function secretIt( str ){
    for( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
        var c = str.charCodeAt( i );
        /**
        * check for spaces first
        * check if get outside of the letter range for both lower and upper
        * if we dont go then were good
        * if so go back 26 chars
        */
        str = str.replaceAt( i, String.fromCharCode( ( c == 32 ) ? c : ( ( c = c + 2 ) > 91 && c < 97 || c < 123 ) ? c : c - 26 ) ) ;
    }
    return str;
}

console.log( secretIt( "Qsncp qcapcr ambc" ), ' ' , secretIt( STR ));
```

Answer (score 0):

**C#** 5KB

> (381 chars)

391

```
using System;
namespace WinHelper {
    class P {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            char[] f =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ".ToCharArray();
            char[] g =  "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab ".ToCharArray();

            foreach (char c in Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray().ToLower()) 
                Console.Write(g[Array.FindIndex(f, a => a == c)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiled size (5KB) doesn't matter. For **code-golf** the number of **chars** (of sourcecode) usually counts, but since this particular challenge is a **popularity contest** and not **code-golf** the chars/size doesn't matter at all. Hover your mouse over the `popularity contest` badge beneath the challenge (you'll see a tooltip explaining it: "*A popularity-contest is a competition where the correct answer with the most upvotes wins, `usually the most creative answer`*").

Comment: Also, it crashes on the challenge's example input `Today is a great day` since it doesn't support uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 163

Yes, this is not code-golf. I went for shortest anyway (or at least, made a first stab at it)

```c#
using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(a[0].Select(c=>(char)(c==32?c:c<89?c+2:c<91?c-24:c<121?c+2:c-24))));}}
```

Formatted:

```c#
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(a[0].Select(c => (char)(c == 32 ? c : c < 89 ? c + 2 : c < 91 ? c - 24 : c < 121 ? c + 2 : c - 24))));
    }
}
```

Yes, I did have a peek at [ufis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21125/14039).

Answer (score 0):

## Q

```
{x^(raze a!'rotate[2] each a:.Q`a`A)x}
```

Comment: Which Q language? http://q-lang.sourceforge.net/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28programming_language_from_Kx_Systems%29 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

### Java

```
void sl(String s){
    for (char c: s.toCharArray()){
        char l = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        System.out.print((char)(c + (l < 'y'? l < 'a'? 0: 2: -24)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say this is very similar to this answer: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21002/12205

Comment: ...and I would agree with you :P

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 8 characters

...if you happen to have the bsdgames package installed! Reads from standard input.

```bsh
caesar 2
```

### Example

```bsh
echo Today is a great day|caesar 2
```

Output: `Vqfca ku c itgcv fca`

Answer (score 0):

### C

```
#include <stdio.h>
char c[100];
int main()
{
gets(c);
char *p=c,x;
while(*p)
{
    x=*p;
    if(x>='a'&&x<='z')
    {
        *p=((*p-'a'+2)%(26)+'a');
    }
    if(x>='A'&&x<='Z')
    {
        *p=((*p-'A'+2)%(26)+'A');
    }

    p++;
}
puts(c);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Brainfuck

Must have (at least) 7-bit wrapping cells to work.

```
+[>,>+++++[<------>-]>[<<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>>>+<]>-[<<<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]]<]
```

- Infinite input loop `+[`
- Get input `>,`
- Make a loop to get number 30 `>+++++[<------>-]>`
- If the symbol is a space, output the space `[<<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>>>+<]>-`
- Otherwise, shift the ASCII value by two and output `[<<<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]]<`
- Get more input `]`

Comment: Timtech, you really like posting esoteric solutions without explaining what they do. When posting your answers, don't forget the explanation.

Comment: -30 will always be true so it will just output the first character as is infinitely.

Comment: @Quincunx Explanation added.

Comment: @Sylwester Fixed.

Comment: Still doesn't work. `Today is a great day` turns into `Vqfc{"ku"c"itgcv"fc{` instead of `Vqfca ku c itgcv fca`which means it doesn't wrap at yY and spaces are translated too.

Comment: @Sylwester You need to use 7-bit wrapping cells

Comment: @Timtech Very unusual cell size and I read at least as it would have to be a minimum. Where do you get a 7 bit interpreter?

Comment: @Sylwester It can be eight or more, they just have to wrap. That's a requirement.

Comment: @Timtech 8 bit wrapping I can do and my interpreter is still printing `Vqfc{"ku"c"itgcv"fc{` instead of `Vqfca ku c itgcv fca`.