# Create a CleverBot

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

[CleverBot](http://www.cleverbot.com/) is a conversational AI that works fundamentally by repeating responses from real humans it has heard previously. It starts off pretty dumb, but once the database becomes *(a lot)* larger it begins sounding more like an actual person!

### How your program should work

1. **Output `Hi!`**
2. **Receive the user's reply as a string**

   - The reply is added to a list of responses associated with the program's last output (eg. the first reply would associate with `Hi!`).
3. **Output one of the responses associated with the reply from step 2**

   - Every output has a list of responses associated with it.
   - The response should be randomly selected from the list of associated responses.
   - Matching of previous replies is case-insensitive and without symbols (only `0-9`, `A-Z` and space are matched). For example, entering `hi` could return any response associated with `hi`, `Hi!`, `///H|||I\\\`, etc.
   - If the user's reply does not match any previous responses, randomly select a response from the **entire** list of responses.
4. **Repeat steps 2 and 3 indefinitely**

### Rules

- Output must be exactly the same as the user originally entered it
- If a reply that needs to be added to the list of responses is already in the list, it can be optionally be added again (so it appears in the list twice)
- Input will never be empty and will only contain printable ASCII (code points `32` to `126`)
- All possible random values must have an equal chance of occurring
- Must be a full program (not just a function)
- Must output to `STDOUT` or closest equivalent
- Must take input from `STDIN` or closest equivalent

### Test Case

```
Hi!
> hi...
hi...
> HI
HI                               // could output "hi..." or "HI"
> How are you?
How are you?                     // could output "hi...", "HI" or "How are you?"
> Good.
Good.                            // could output "hi...", "HI", "How are you?" or "Good."
> ~!@#$*`'"(how ar%&e you_\|./<?
Good.
> Good.
~!@#$*`'"(how ar%&e you_\|./<?   // could output "~!@#..." or "Good."
> 2Good.
HI                               // could output any of the user's previous replies
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20914/34543).

Comment: Can there be two responses associated to one reply?

Comment: @TanMath Yes, there can and should. Each reply has a list of responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6) <s>155</s> 148 bytes

```
c=t=>t.replace(/[^\dA-Z ]/gi,"");r=["Hi!"];for(a=[],m={};u=prompt(alert(o=r[new Date%r.length]));r=m[c(u)]||a)(m[o=c(o)]=m[o]||[]).push(u),a.push(u)
```

### Less golfed:

```
c=t=>t.replace(/[^\dA-Z ]/gi,"");
r=["Hi!"];
for(a=[], m={}; u=prompt( alert( o=r[new Date%r.length] ) );
r= m [ c(u) ] || a )( m[ o=c(o) ] = m[o] || [] ).push(u), a.push(u)
```

- *3 bytes saved thanks to @balint*

Comment: Use the date tehnique for randoms `new Date%(r.length|0)`